# Can't create custom attributes in Azure AD B2C with asp.net core Graph API

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

In my Azure B2C directory I have created a custom attribute called `EmployeeId`. I am creating the users with the Microsoft Graph library. I followed the example from this [GitHub Example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management).

My actual user creation code looks like this:

```cs
public async Task InsertEmployee(Employee employee) 
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> extensionInstance = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            extensionInstance.Add("EmployeeId", employee.EmployeeId.ToString());

            var user = new B2cUserModel
            {
                DisplayName = $"{employee.EmployeeFirstName} {employee.EmployeeLastName}",
                GivenName = employee.EmployeeFirstName,
                Surname = employee.EmployeeLastName,
                Password = employee.Password,
                Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity> {
                    new ObjectIdentity {
                        SignInType = "emailAddress",
                        IssuerAssignedId = employee.EmployeeEmail
                    }
                },
                EmployeeId = employee.EmployeeId.ToString()
                AdditionalData = extensionInstance
            };

            user.SetB2CProfile(_domain);
            await _client.Users.Request().AddAsync(user);
        }
    }
```

But whenever I retrieve the user details either through code or through a user_flow EmployeeId is always null. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi lenny, have you tried my solution? If there is any further concern please let me know.

Comment: Hey Allen, yes I did try your solution. It told me there was no attribute called 'extension_{client_id}_EmployeeId'. (I didn't actually put {client_id}, but the actual client id). I was running short on time so I have placed the employeeId in Job Title for now. When I get time I'll come back and look at this again. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Please find the WebApp-GraphAPI-DirectoryExtensions app in App registrations. I think you put a wrong app id.

Answer (score 0):

The custom attribute in Azure B2C is stored in Graph as such a format: `extension_{client id of WebApp-GraphAPI-DirectoryExtensions}_{custom attribute}`. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api#extension-properties).

You can find the client id of WebApp-GraphAPI-DirectoryExtensions Azure AD app in **Azure Portal** -> **App registrations**.

So in this case, you should use:

```
extensionInstance.Add("extension_{client id of WebApp-GraphAPI-DirectoryExtensions}_EmployeeId", employee.EmployeeId.ToString());
```